# Getting error "Could not start SUMO" while following Veins tutorial

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm fairly new to Omnet++ and I'm trying to follow the tutorial (https://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/) to set up Veins. I ran into an error at the final Step "Run the Veins demo scenario". Using SUMO 1.2.0 and Veins 4.7.1

I made sure that the Path variables are added correctly for SUMO and tested it's working by checking the SUMO version in cmd.
I've also made sure that omnet++ itself is working properly by running other projects such as the tictoc example.
However in the final step in the tutorial, when I try to launch the configuration, it starts listening on port 9999 as expected, but it never starts SUMO and I get the error below:

```
Could not start SUMO (C:/Users/user/Downloads/Sumo/bin/sumo-gui.exe -c erlangen.sumo.cfg): [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I made sure that I'm running the command from the correct context where the erlangen.sumo.cfg file exists.

I have also ran the erlangen.sumo.cfg and it was loaded correctly.

What am I missing here? Appreciate your help.

```
/c/Users/maria/Downloads/veins-4.7.1/veins-veins-4.7.1/examples/veins$ sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg
Loading configuration... done.
```

```
/c/Users/maria/Downloads/veins-4.7.1/veins-veins-4.7.1/examples/veins$ /c/Users/maria/Downloads/veins-4.7.1/veins-veins-4.7.1/sumo-launchd.py -vv -c /c/Users/user/Downloads/Sumo/bin/sumo-gui.exe
Logging to c:/users/maria/appdata/local/temp/sumo-launchd.log
Listening on port 9999
Connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 64943
Handling connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 64943
Got TraCI message of length 2
Got TraCI command of length 1
Got TraCI command 0x0
Got CMD_GETVERSION
Got TraCI message of length 319
Got TraCI command of length 314
Got TraCI command 0x75
Got CMD_FILE_SEND for "sumo-launchd.launch.xml"
Got CMD_FILE_SEND with data "<launch>
  <copy file="erlangen.net.xml"/>
  <copy file="erlangen.rou.xml"/>
  <copy file="erlangen.poly.xml"/>
  <copy file="erlangen.sumo.cfg" type="config"/>
  <basedir path="C:/Users/maria/Downloads/veins-4.7.1/veins-veins-4.7.1/examples/veins/"/>
  <seed value="0"/>
</launch>
"
Creating temporary directory...
Temporary dir is c:/users/maria/appdata/local/temp/sumo-launchd-tmp-9wfgio
Base dir is C:/Users/maria/Downloads/veins-4.7.1/veins-veins-4.7.1/examples/veins/
Seed is 0
Finding free port number...
Claiming lock on port
...found port 64944
Starting SUMO (C:/Users/user/Downloads/Sumo/bin/sumo-gui.exe -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 64944, seed 0
Releasing lock on port
Cleaning up
Result: "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<status>
        <exit-code>-1</exit-code>
        <start>1564500716</start>
        <end>1564500716</end>
        <status>Could not start SUMO (C:/Users/user/Downloads/Sumo/bin/sumo-gui.exe -c erlangen.sumo.cfg): [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified</status>
        <stdout><![CDATA[]]></stdout>
        <stderr><![CDATA[]]></stderr>
</status>
"
Closing connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 64943
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I set up SUMO in any other path than C:\Users\user\src\sumo-0.32.0, it doesn't work.

So when I removed SUMO and downloaded it in that path, it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Veins 4.7. is not compatible with newer versions of SUMO. To run Veins example, install SUMO 0.32.

If you need newer SUMO, you can try SUMO 1.1 with Veins 5.1a. Be aware that this is alpha version and it might be unstable.

Comment: I have installed SUMO 0.32 and tried to re run the simulation, but still got the same error.

Comment: I think you got the same error because Veins still tried to run SUMO 1.2. I see from your other answer that you resolved the issue by setting the path to supported version correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked `sumo-launchd.py` to run SUMO as `Sumo/bin/sumo.exe`, but your system cannot find the file specified. Most likely, you need to run SUMO more like this `/c/Users/user/src/sumo-0.25.0/bin/sumo.exe` (depending on where you put sumo.exe)

Comment: yes, that was it. I had to use the path /c/Users/user/src/sumo-0.25.0/bin/sumo.exe. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please make it as answered!